# Issues setting up Parcel with Pug and multiple entry points

Tags: parcel, pug-loader

I am trying to set up Parcel with Pug and multiple entry points. I have combed [through the docs](https://parceljs.org/pug.html) but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Right now I have two main issues:

1. The CSS is only being loaded into `about.html` on build and not `index.html`.
2. The HTML files are being built but I need them to be built into folders. So `about.pug` should be built as `about/index.html`. How can I build the pug files into their respective folders: `page/index.html`?

Project structure:

```
 src
    ├── js
    │   └── index.js
    ├── pug
    │   ├── about.pug
    │   ├── index.pug
    │   └── layouts
    │       └── default.pug
    └── styles
        └── main.scss
```

Both `about.pug` and `index.pug` are using a default layout in `src/layouts/default.pug`.

The `SCSS` file is being imported in `index.js` like this:

`import "../styles/main.scss";`

but for some reason the CSS is only getting imported into `about.html` and not `index.html` at build time.

Here are my `package.json` build scripts:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "parcel src/pug/*.pug",
   "build": "parcel build src/pug/*.pug"
}
```

Here is a repo if you want to take a look: [github repository](https://github.com/joelhoelting/parcel-pug-example)